# Monodroid - Monodevelop wipes user data while deploying to device

Tags: android, mono, monodevelop, xamarin.android

Using Mono for Android, Monodevelop 2.8.6.5

Deploying to real device (like to emulator too) always wipes user data (files, shared preferences, sqlite tables, etc). Is there any way to prevent it?

This problem was solved for Visual Studio here ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/7669912/792367 ) but I can't find solution for MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mono for Android on MonoDevelop has had this feature for a few months now. It won't wipe user data on redeploy, and if you have the Fast Deployment option on, it won't even send the entire package, just the changed assemblies. You need to check the MonoDevelop and Mono for Android versions you have installed and make sure they're up to date.

Comment: Please look at my comment to answer below. I'm looking for some checkbox or .ini option to enabe/disable wiping.

Comment: There isn't any option for this, the apk installation always keeps user data. If you want to clear it, you just uninstall the app from the device.

Comment: Also, in MonoDevelop, if you have the android project (or one of its files) selected, there will be an extra menu entry in the Project menu called "Uninstall...", which is a quick way of uninstalling your app if you need to.

Answer (score 8):

This is the default Android deployment behavior. However, there is an option in MonoDevelop's Preferences to override it:

[image: Preserve data/cache between application deploys]

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Preserve-User-Data-Between-Deploys-td4811808.html

MonoDevelop does not have this feature yet.

Comment: Actually, question under your link is dated about 6 months ago. My colleague at the next table has Monodevelop setupped to fresh OS few days ago, and when he deploys to device his userdata keeps alive. Looks like this feature was recently added, but there is no any switcher or option to check. I have Mono setupped 6 months ago and now updated to last version, but my data still wipes.